# How to log in/ log out using spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication, postman

I'm trying to make log in and log out system with spring boot, I have a database class that contains users info, I register users using HTTP requests in POSTMAN, my question is how I can log in and log out users with GUI/Web/HTML, only in POSTMAN, and prevent users to request a specific URL unless they are logged in?

Comment: Check [Spring Security](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security)

Comment: Ok I will check it, thank u :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring, you should take a look to spring security. This for example is a tutorial explaining how to set up a login form using spring security

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login

In addition to this, yo cannot prevent a user to make a request but using spring security you can check if a specific user has the credentials to perform an operation using a cookie, or token...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much infrastructure you are willing to implement.
I would say that a minimum control could be based on a simple filter that verifies the session or autehtication already active, and endpoints to authenticate and set that session and other destroy it.
But if you need a little more (and probably you will) it would be worth directly think of doing a minimal spring security integration and implement the standard